# Should I start going to tournaments?

Tags: tae-kwon-do

I am an advanced high purple belt and I was told by my sensei that I should start going to tournaments to improve my experience. I have never been to nor seen a tournament, but I do not know if I should start going across the country. I am completely undecided on this, answering would be a lot of help.

Comment: I voted to close as this is really a personal question that no one but yourself can answer: I cannot see there being a possible best answer that would be useful to a larger audience.

Comment: This needs to be narrowed down. What are your goals? What do you hope to get out of tournaments? Why don't you want to go?

Comment: What style? Why going across country? Can you not go watch a tournament first? Way too many details left out.